# Invalid Swift entry point data

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Whenever I run my watchOS app, I get this error message in the console. Could this be the issue, why my WCSession cannot run as intended?

> *** WatchKit Extension[33667:3380818] [default] lookupMainFuncAddressInMachHeader:71: Invalid Swift entry point data
>
> *** WatchKit Extension[33667:3380818] [default] lookupMainFuncAddressInMachHeader:77: Swift entry point addres could
> not be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it does not influence the WCSession.